# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I have the following JSON

```
{
"response": {
  "feedMessageResponse": {
     "count": 1,
     "feed": {
        "id": "0nOCG6C0TBCMWdT0YPQYm4n8zxxxxgDQ",
        "name": "Nav1",
        "description": "Nav 1",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "usage": 0,
        "daysRange": 7,
        "detailedMessageShown": true
     },
     "totalCount": 1,
     "activityCount": 0,
     "messages": {
        "message": {
           "@clientUnixTime": "0",
           "id": 464064302,
           "messengerId": "0-8061742",
           "messengerName": "Navigator1",
           "unixTime": 1445904943,
           "messageType": "OK",
           "latitude": -39.1234,
           "longitude": 140.1234,
           "modelId": "SPOT2",
           "showCustomMsg": "Y",
           "dateTime": "2015-10-27T00:15:43+0000",
           "batteryState": "GOOD",
           "hidden": 0,
           "messageContent": "We have reached this place safely."
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

There are heaps of properties but when there is only 1 response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message I get a deserialization error stating:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[ITBeyond.Mapping.Tracking+SpotMessenger+Message]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path
>   'response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message.@clientUnixTime', line
>   1, position 287.

If there is more than one message it works fine. The two properties around this error are defined as:

```
Public Class Messages
            <JsonProperty("message")> _
            Public Property Message() As IList(Of Message)
                Get
                    Return m_Message
                End Get
                Set(value As IList(Of Message))
                    m_Message = value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_Message As IList(Of Message)
        End Class

        Public Class Message
            <JsonProperty("@clientUnixTime")> _
            Public Property ClientUnixTime() As String
                Get
                    Return m_ClientUnixTime
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    m_ClientUnixTime = value
                End Set
            End Property
         Private m_ClientUnixTime As String
```

I have spent ages looking for this and wonder if there is a problem with the @. I have also tried changing to an array of Message but got a similar error. Any ideas.

When there are more than one it is like this - it goes to an array of message:

```
{"response":{"feedMessageResponse":{"count":50,"feed":{"id":"065QbDkxboXg22n86GUPEQeuauruGOYBi","name":"SPOT XML","description":"SPOT XML","status":"ACTIVE","usage":0,"daysRange":7,"detailedMessageShown":true},"totalCount":182,"activityCount":0,"messages":{"message":[{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464123101,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445922060,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19292,"longitude":149.03433,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T05:01:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464122174,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445921763,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19292,"longitude":149.0343,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:56:03+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464121461,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445921495,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19289,"longitude":149.0343,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:51:35+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464120694,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445921168,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19308,"longitude":149.03423,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:46:08+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464115761,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445919383,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19321,"longitude":149.03415,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:16:23+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464115023,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445919086,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19305,"longitude":149.03415,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:11:26+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464114294,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445918788,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19316,"longitude":149.03424,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:06:28+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464113424,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445918490,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.1931,"longitude":149.03429,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T04:01:30+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464112469,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445918192,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19315,"longitude":149.03419,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:56:32+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464111792,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445917972,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.19928,"longitude":149.0296,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:52:52+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464110787,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445917597,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.24193,"longitude":149.02847,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:46:37+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464109932,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445917299,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.27621,"longitude":149.0704,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:41:39+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464109006,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445917001,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.33484,"longitude":149.06393,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:36:41+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464108035,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445916704,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.38843,"longitude":149.06499,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:31:44+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464107372,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445916504,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.41505,"longitude":149.07426,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:28:24+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464106371,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445916108,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.43842,"longitude":149.12648,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:21:48+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464105481,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445915810,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.50751,"longitude":149.15002,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:16:50+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464105500,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445915510,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.57841,"longitude":149.13551,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:11:50+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464105501,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445915210,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.64789,"longitude":149.16358,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T03:06:50+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464101543,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445914618,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.79567,"longitude":149.164,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:56:58+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464100848,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445914356,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.85545,"longitude":149.159,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:52:36+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464099729,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445914020,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.93443,"longitude":149.14832,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:47:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464098656,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445913720,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-35.99512,"longitude":149.14024,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:42:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464097685,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445913420,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.06444,"longitude":149.15785,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:37:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464096538,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445913120,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.13341,"longitude":149.14516,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:32:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464095566,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445912820,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.20546,"longitude":149.15779,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:27:00+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464094635,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445912523,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.2339,"longitude":149.12524,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T02:22:03+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464088627,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445910814,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.2343,"longitude":149.125,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:53:34+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464087388,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445910496,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.23421,"longitude":149.12494,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:48:16+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464086179,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445910198,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.23412,"longitude":149.12503,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:43:18+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464085139,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445909900,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.23065,"longitude":149.13393,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:38:20+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464084097,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445909603,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.20473,"longitude":149.18015,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:33:23+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464083098,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445909306,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.19275,"longitude":149.26016,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:28:26+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464082096,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445909008,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.17796,"longitude":149.33478,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:23:28+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464080863,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445908711,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.16394,"longitude":149.38853,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:18:31+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464078674,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445908116,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.22205,"longitude":149.453,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:08:36+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464077782,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445907875,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.25075,"longitude":149.46568,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T01:04:35+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464076447,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445907521,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.29175,"longitude":149.49706,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:58:41+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464074638,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445907066,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.31458,"longitude":149.51871,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:51:06+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464072740,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445906629,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.30792,"longitude":149.53412,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:43:49+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464072770,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445906329,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.29522,"longitude":149.54717,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:38:49+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464072771,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445906029,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.28672,"longitude":149.56039,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:33:49+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464069450,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445905738,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.28976,"longitude":149.57068,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-27T00:28:58+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464060210,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445903953,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.26187,"longitude":149.65543,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T23:59:13+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":464059043,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445903656,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.2618,"longitude":149.65604,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T23:54:16+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":463751797,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445837736,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.2618,"longitude":149.65614,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T05:35:36+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":463751009,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445837439,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.26195,"longitude":149.65622,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T05:30:39+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":463751022,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445837139,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.26195,"longitude":149.65622,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T05:25:39+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":463751023,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445836839,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.26174,"longitude":149.65571,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T05:20:39+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0},{"@clientUnixTime":"0","id":463743223,"messengerId":"0-2427832","messengerName":"CSGen3 No1","unixTime":1445834462,"messageType":"UNLIMITED-TRACK","latitude":-36.26802,"longitude":149.75372,"modelId":"SPOT3","showCustomMsg":"Y","dateTime":"2015-10-26T04:41:02+0000","batteryState":"GOOD","hidden":0}]}}}}
```

Comment: There's only one `message` object in the `messages` object.  What does the JSON look like when there is more than one message?

Comment: See here: [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n).  There's even a VB.NET answer included.

Comment: I have updated the question with the multiple message example.

Comment: Looks like you could use `<JsonConverter(GetType(SingleValueArrayConverter(Of Message))>` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n/32628995#32628995 on the `"message"` property.

Comment: @dbc - perfect just implemented it and it works - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by dbc provided the answer. I had to vb.net the code so here is the converted code and answer:

Convert the message to use a custom JsonConverter

```
        Public Class Messages
            <JsonProperty("message")>
            <JsonConverter(GetType(SingleOrArrayConverter(Of Message)))>
            Public Property Message() As IList(Of Message)
                Get
                    Return m_Message
                End Get
                Set(value As IList(Of Message))
                    m_Message = value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_Message As IList(Of Message)
        End Class
```

Implement the SingleOrArrayConverter (VB version)

```
      Class SingleOrArrayConverter(Of T)
            Inherits JsonConverter
            Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
                Return (objectType = GetType(List(Of T)))
            End Function

            Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
                Dim token As JToken = JToken.Load(reader)
                If token.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
                    Return token.ToObject(Of List(Of T))()
                End If
                Return New List(Of T)() From {
                    token.ToObject(Of T)()
                }
            End Function

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite() As Boolean
                Get
                    Return False
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
                Throw New NotImplementedException()
            End Sub
        End Class
```